# Drawing.Graphics Line intersection add color in c#

Tags: c#, gdi+

I'm actually developing a 2d graphic application that consist on drawing lines based on a specific hardware readings.

Actually, using System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawLine i'm able to draw the lines (this is the easy part).

But also, I need the intersection between two lines (the common pixel in both lines) to be identified, and also to be painted in other color than the line.

I've been trying with regions and graphicpaths, but I can't find the way to identify the common pixel (insersection) between two lines.

Can anybody help me?

Thank you, regards.

Answer (score 0):

[calculate the intersection between two lines](http://www.google.com/search?q=calculate+the+intersection+between+two+lines&rlz=1I7DASE_sv&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7)